# Calling dlsym() with a NULL handle doesn't return NULL, but rather returns a random function

Tags: c++, c, linux, dlopen, dlsym

My title may not be clear, so allow me to explain. I have a piece of code that goes like this:

```
void* pluginFile = dlopen(fileName, RTLD_LAZY);
auto function = dlsym(pluginFile, "ExpectedFunction");
```

This works fine if `dlopen` returns the right file. My problem is when `dlopen` doesn't find a file and returns `NULL`. What currently happens is that this call is made:

```
dlsym(0x0, "ExpectedFunction");
```

The problem is that this returns a random function in my project called `ExpectedFunction`. What I thought would happen is that dlsym would return `NULL` since the passed handle is `NULL`. I'm not able to find the expected behavior for such a use case online.

My question is, what is supposed to happen when you pass a `NULL` handle to `dlsym`? Will it simply return `NULL` or will it interpret it as a handle at location `0x0`? If the inteded behavior is the latter, then I'll simply add a check to make sure dlopen `suceeded`. If not, I'd like to know why it randomly returns a function with the same name from an other library if the handle is `NULL`.

My current use case is that I am loading 10 shared libraries that I made that all have a function `ExpectedFunction()`. However, if we call `dlopen` with a filename of a shared library that does not exist, it will return `NULL`. Then, `dlsym` will return a pointer to `ExpectedFunction()` of the last library that was loaded.

Comment: Looks like your implementation uses `#define RTLD_DEFAULT ((void*)0)`, so your null pointer is indeed interpreted as "whichever you find first".

Comment: A good habit to get into:  Whenever you call some API function (like dlopen) that has a return value that clearly indicates if it has failed, always check it and act appropriately as soon as you can, rather than relying the value being safe to use elsewhere.   It pays to get religion about it.  Not only does it save you from "gotcha" situations like this (which might not get discovered in testing) but it makes it clearer to those who come after you what ought to happen.

Comment: @Joe I'll definitely keep that in mind from now on!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is, what is supposed to happen when you pass a NULL handle to dlsym?

The specification says:

> If handle does not refer to a valid object opened by dlopen() ... dlsym() shall return NULL.

**However**, there are some reserved handle values that have special behaviour. If you pass such reserved handle, then the behaviour is different. The exact values are unspecified by POSIX, but for example in glibc:

```
# define RTLD_NEXT        ((void *) -1l)
# define RTLD_DEFAULT        ((void *) 0)
```

`(void *) 0` is null, and therefore you accidentally passed `RTLD_DEFAULT` into `dlsym`. Of this, the spec says:

> `RTLD_DEFAULT`
>
> The symbol lookup happens in the normal global scope; that is, a search for a symbol using this handle would find the same definition as a direct use of this symbol in the program code.

So, in conclusion, what is supposed to happen depends on whether NULL is a reserved value or not. It happens to be reserved in glibc, but is not necessarily so in other implementations.

You should check that `dlopen` does not return null (or check that `dlerror` does return null) before passing to `dlsym`.

Comment: Note: `RTLD_DEFAULT` is defined for some (most) other POSIX C libraries (like the one for FreeBSD or macOS), but it is not equal to `NULL` there. Therefore better use `RTLD_DEFAULT` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

From the `dlfcn.h` on Ubuntu Linux:

```
/* If the first argument to `dlsym' or `dlvsym' is set to RTLD_DEFAULT
   the run-time address of the symbol called NAME in the global scope
   is returned.  */
# define RTLD_DEFAULT   ((void *) 0)
```

and from `dlsym` man-page:

> RTLD_DEFAULT
>
> Find the first occurrence of the desired symbol using the default shared object search  order. The search  will  include  global  symbols in the executable and its dependencies, as well as symbols in shared objects that were dynamically loaded with the RTLD_GLOBAL flag.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!